# UI-GRID Usage In An Angular 2 App

Tags: angular, angular-ui-grid

We are building an angular 2 app to replace an existing angular 1 app. We use ui-grid in the angular1 app and will need to use it in the angular 2 app.

Is there a way to wrap the ui-grid so that we can use it in an angular 2 app?

Is there a beta angular 2 UI-GRID that we can use?

Thanks